How to remove custom TabBar background - React Native Expo
I created my own tab bar using Expo navigation, which is not filling the screen width but there is a grey background behind it and I can't find how to remove it.
The background is NOT part of the component.
You can see it here
Here is my _layout component:
function HomeLayout() {
    return (
        <Tabs screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
        tabBar={props => <TabBar {...props}/>}>
            <Tabs.Screen name={"browse/index"} options={{title: "Browse"}}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name={"likes/index"} options={{title: "Likes"}}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name={"messages/index"} options={{title: "Messages"}}/>
            <Tabs.Screen name={"premium/index"} options={{title: "Premium"}}/>
        </Tabs>
    )
}

and the TapBar custom component:
function TabBar({navigation, state, descriptors}) {


    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={styles.secondaryContainer}>

                {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
                    const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
                    const label = options.tabBarLabel !== undefined ? options.tabBarLabel : options.title !== undefined ? options.title : route.name;

                    const isFocused = state.index === index;

                    const onPress = () => {
                        const event = navigation.emit({
                            type: 'tabPress', target: route.key,
                        });

                        if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
                            navigation.navigate(route.name);
                        }
                    };

                    return (
                        <LinearGradient key={index}
                                        colors={isFocused ? GRADIENT_1.colors : TRANSPARENT_GRADIENT.colors}
                                        start={GRADIENT_1.start}
                                        end={GRADIENT_1.end}
                                  style={[styles.mainItemContainer, {borderRightWidth: label == "notes" ? 3 : 0}]}>
                            <Pressable
                                onPress={onPress}
                                style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}>
                            </Pressable>
                        </LinearGradient>);
                })}
            </View>
        </View>
    );

